# set meta tag content value to True through site url

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an html page with meta tag :

```
<meta name="mytag" content="False">
```

I'm looking to set meta tag content to True from site URL.

I've tried to add it using "&mytag=True"

https://www.example.com/#&mytag=True

but it doesn't work

Any help ?

Comment: Set target url in content attribute?

Comment: set meta content value to true, by default it's set to false

Comment: `document.querySelector("meta[name='mytag']").setAttribute("content", "true")`

Comment: `<meta name="mytag" content="<?= $_GET['mytag'] || 'False'; ?> ">` ?